# Can't expose thingsboard to internet

Tags: thingsboard

I installed thingsboard on ubuntu server on a VM in Microsoft Azure, it works locally when I execute the command curl http://localhost:8080/ it gives me HTML output which means its fine, but when I try to access it from the public IP address of the VM its says that the [IPADRESS]/ refused connexion,
so I installed Apache2 to test, well it works fine, I can access apache default home page from public IP of the VM, without any special config.
so my question is:  is there any method or configuration to make so it works, it's my graduation project.
thanks in advance.

the output of curl:

```
Copyright © 2016-2020 The Thingsboard Authors

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" style="width: 100%;">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ThingsBoard</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="thingsboard.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.847f14359bb6ee347331.css"></head>
<body class="tb-default">
  <tb-root></tb-root>
<script src="runtime.2b494f2d73c5bde039e8.js" defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.8a208a1c49b1e6cc29c7.js" nomodule defer></scrip
t><script src="polyfills.ca00bc0fb42cd6555628.js" defer></script><script src="scripts.ecbfdd170a33c541f312.js" defer></script><script s
rc="vendor.3b9f5195c7405cac33d5.js" defer></script><script src="main.07d346237608c10a5df8.js" defer></script></body>
</html>
```